# Return the entire nested, generated code of a dynamic Python class

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, python-decorators, dynamically-generated

Given a decorated class like this in Python 2.7:

```
import attr

@attr.s(slots=True, frozen=True)
class User(object):
    name = attr.ib(
        validator=attr.validators.instance_of(str),
        converter=lambda _name: str(_name).upper(),
    )
    id = attr.ib(validator=attr.validators.instance_of(int))


print(User("bob", 123))
# User(name='BOB', id=123)
```

How to get all the generated *class code* so I could theoretically copy the output into a new class. The best I can do is:

```
import inspect
print(inspect.getsource(User.__init__))
```

Output:

```
def __init__(self, name, id):
    _setattr = _cached_setattr.__get__(self, self.__class__)
    _setattr('name', __attr_converter_name(name))
    _setattr('id', id)
    if _config._run_validators is True:
        __attr_validator_name(self, __attr_name, self.name)
        __attr_validator_id(self, __attr_id, self.id)
```

Then I need the nested source for `_cached_setattr` and `__attr_validator_name` and `__attr_validator_id` and so forth. Is there a method or technique that will recursively walk the class and do something like `inspect.getsource` on every method until a class definition that can stand on its own is printed?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you would need to do this?

Comment: Why are you assuming `attr` generates the kind of source code you're looking for?

Comment: Yes. The real implementation has something like 20 of these attribs and even more decorators. I need to demonstrate that using static source code (with tweaks and shortcuts in the validation) is faster than using attrib sugar in "hot" code iff I can show the stakeholders what this is doing under the hood.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica The case could be made for a `type("Foo", (object,), {})` class as well. Here, it is clearly attr because that is all that is there, and the under method prefixes support that.

Comment: "I need to demonstrate that using static source code (with tweaks and shortcuts in the validation) is faster than using attrib sugar in "hot" code." - Then write it yourself. `attr` doesn't work the way you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, but that does not answer the question and it's a fair question. I need to show stakeholders what this is doing under the hood, so yes, I can write it by hand. Since we're going on a tangent, this is not my code, I suspect it is a bottleneck, and no I wasn't given time to refactor everything.

Comment: If I can show that using `attr` adds a bazillion internal validation methods to the class, then maybe I can make a case to refactor our codebase. Make sense?

Comment: Some parts of `attr` use code generation, but the code generation doesn't work in such a way that you could just dump all the generated code into a file together and get a standalone class definition. `attr` does add some validation stuff, but it's validation you *asked for* - you'd have the same validation either way, just written more directly if you did it manually.

Comment: There is no "class code". Each time a code snippet is compiled, the source code is attached to it. The source of `User` is what you wrote in OP. The source of `User.__init__` is, again, what you wrote - the code string built by `attrs`, compiled and inserted into `User` (and this will not change the string set as `User` source). If you want to see everything going on in `User` at a glance, `import dis; dis.dis(User)` is the only thing that will give you the actual code of your `User` class.

Comment: Rather than trying to generate a standalone class definition from `attr` output, why not just *compare* the performance of a class that uses `attr` and a class with the boilerplate written manually? You'll be able to test your hypothesis that `attr` slows things down, and if you're right, you'll be able to give stakeholders concrete performance numbers instead of telling them "wow, look at all this generated code, it's *gotta* be slow, right?"

Comment: I agree with @user2357112supportsMonica . I started digging through the `attr.s` implementation, and these vars used during the method invocation are passed in as globals during the evaluation of the `__init__` method. They are not directly included in the generated class. See the source for [_compile_and_eval](https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs/blob/83d3cd70f90a3f4d19ee8b508e58d1c58821c0ad/src/attr/_make.py#L314-L319). The easiest way to test performance would be to A/B test a hand crafted version of the class and compare that to the one generated by attrs.

Comment: Yep. In particular, `_cached_setattr` does not have a source; it is the built-in `object.__setattr__`, cached for speed.

Comment: Thank you @flakes, \@user2357112, and \@Amadan

Answer (score 1):

Wonderful comments from everyone. Thank you.

> Rather than trying to generate a standalone class definition from attr output, why not just compare the performance of a class that uses attr and a class with the boilerplate written manually?

Replied in comments, but again the actual entity that may be a bottleneck has something like **20 of these attributes** with validators and converters (yuck) and even more decorators - this all add ups and it not easy to rewrite for an A/B. First I need to show I can even do a better job before an A/B gets sanctioned.

> There is no "class code". Each time a code snippet is compiled, the source code is attached to it. The source of `User` is what you wrote in OP. The source of `User.__init__` is, again, what you wrote.

Yes and no. I did not write `init`, `@attr` did, but again to your point the validators were hinted at by me (`instance_of` is syntactic sugar), but *massaged* by `@attr`.

> If you want to see everything going on in User at a glance, `import dis; dis.dis(User)`.

Good call. Here is the disassembly of that wee class with two attributes. And yes, the most important parts are cached globally, **but only inside `__init__`**

```
Disassembly of __init__:
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (__attr_converter_name)
```

Full disassembly:

```
Disassembly of __eq__:
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                1 (other)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                0 (__class__)
              6 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
              9 LOAD_ATTR                0 (__class__)
             12 COMPARE_OP               9 (is not)
             15 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       22
  3          18 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (NotImplemented)
             21 RETURN_VALUE        
  5     >>   22 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
             25 LOAD_ATTR                2 (name)
  6          28 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
             31 LOAD_ATTR                3 (id)
             34 BUILD_TUPLE              2
  8          37 LOAD_FAST                1 (other)
             40 LOAD_ATTR                2 (name)
  9          43 LOAD_FAST                1 (other)
             46 LOAD_ATTR                3 (id)
             49 BUILD_TUPLE              2
             52 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             55 RETURN_VALUE        
Disassembly of __ge__:
1825           0 LOAD_FAST                1 (other)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                0 (__class__)
              6 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
              9 LOAD_ATTR                0 (__class__)
             12 COMPARE_OP               8 (is)
             15 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       40
1826          18 LOAD_DEREF               0 (attrs_to_tuple)
             21 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
             24 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             27 LOAD_DEREF               0 (attrs_to_tuple)
             30 LOAD_FAST                1 (other)
             33 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             36 COMPARE_OP               5 (>=)
             39 RETURN_VALUE        
1828     >>   40 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (NotImplemented)
             43 RETURN_VALUE        
Disassembly of __getstate__:
912           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (tuple)
              3 LOAD_CLOSURE             0 (self)
              6 BUILD_TUPLE              1
              9 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <genexpr> at 0x7f27325e72b0, file "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/attr/_make.py", line 912>)
             12 MAKE_CLOSURE             0
             15 LOAD_DEREF               1 (state_attr_names)
             18 GET_ITER            
             19 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             22 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             25 RETURN_VALUE        
Disassembly of __gt__:
1816           0 LOAD_FAST                1 (other)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                0 (__class__)
              6 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
              9 LOAD_ATTR                0 (__class__)
             12 COMPARE_OP               8 (is)
             15 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       40
1817          18 LOAD_DEREF               0 (attrs_to_tuple)
             21 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
             24 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             27 LOAD_DEREF               0 (attrs_to_tuple)
             30 LOAD_FAST                1 (other)
             33 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             36 COMPARE_OP               4 (>)
             39 RETURN_VALUE        
1819     >>   40 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (NotImplemented)
             43 RETURN_VALUE        
Disassembly of __init__:
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (__attr_converter_name)
              3 LOAD_FAST                1 (name)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              9 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
             12 STORE_ATTR               1 (name)
  3          15 LOAD_FAST                2 (id)
             18 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
             21 STORE_ATTR               2 (id)
  4          24 LOAD_GLOBAL              3 (_config)
             27 LOAD_ATTR                4 (_run_validators)
             30 LOAD_GLOBAL              5 (True)
             33 COMPARE_OP               8 (is)
             36 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       80
  5          39 LOAD_GLOBAL              6 (__attr_validator_name)
             42 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
             45 LOAD_GLOBAL              7 (__attr_name)
             48 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
             51 LOAD_ATTR                1 (name)
             54 CALL_FUNCTION            3
             57 POP_TOP             
  6          58 LOAD_GLOBAL              8 (__attr_validator_id)
             61 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
             64 LOAD_GLOBAL              9 (__attr_id)
             67 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
             70 LOAD_ATTR                2 (id)
             73 CALL_FUNCTION            3
             76 POP_TOP             
             77 JUMP_FORWARD             0 (to 80)
        >>   80 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             83 RETURN_VALUE        
Disassembly of __le__:
1807           0 LOAD_FAST                1 (other)
... snip ....
```

But, if we look in `globals()`, nada.

[image: globals]

If we step into the `User.__init__` method, we see a different story.

[image: globals inside init]

When we leave `__init__`, those globals **are gone!** I'm not sure how the `@attr` package gets globals scoped to only the `__init__` with this snippet in `_main.py`:

```
def _compile_and_eval(script, globs, locs=None, filename=""):
    """
    "Exec" the script with the given global (globs) and local (locs) variables.
    """
    bytecode = compile(script, filename, "exec")
    eval(bytecode, globs, locs)
```

But magic happens here, and it stops me from dumping a complete picture of the `__init__`.

---

To try to answer my question anyway, I started writing the *start* of a recursive script to dump the "full" class. I'm giving up on this because of Python magic, but for what it is worth, `@attr` adds a **lot** more.

```
import attr
import inspect
import types


@attr.s(slots=True, frozen=False)
class User(object):
    name = attr.ib(
        validator=attr.validators.instance_of(str),
        converter=lambda _name: str(_name).upper(),
    )
    id = attr.ib(validator=attr.validators.instance_of(int))


def public_dir(obj):
    return [x for x in dir(obj) if not x.startswith("__")]


def indent(level, txt):
    padding = "    " * level
    print(padding + ("\n" + padding).join(str(txt).rstrip().split("\n")))


def source_all_properties(clazz, level=0):
    indent(level, clazz.__name__)
    props = dir(clazz)
    indent(level, props)
    for p in props:
        indent(level + 1, p)
        if p in clazz.__dict__:
            ref = clazz.__dict__[p]
            indent(level + 2, "type: {}".format(type(ref)))
            if isinstance(ref, types.FunctionType):
                indent(level + 2, "source: " + inspect.getsource(ref))
            elif isinstance(ref, types.ObjectType):
                indent(level + 2, "mros: " + str(inspect.getmro(type(ref))))
                indent(level + 2, "props: " + str(public_dir(ref)))
        else:
            _type = eval("type(clazz.{})".format(p))
            _val = eval("clazz.{}".format(p))
            indent(level + 2, "type: {}: {}".format(_type, _val))

    return level + 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(source_all_properties(User))
```

The output is thus:

```
User
['__attrs_attrs__', '__attrs_own_setattr__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getstate__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setstate__', '__sizeof__', '__slots__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'id', 'name']
    __attrs_attrs__
        type: <class 'UserAttributes'>
        mros: (<class 'UserAttributes'>, <type 'tuple'>, <type 'object'>)
        props: ['count', 'id', 'index', 'name']
    __attrs_own_setattr__
        type: <type 'bool'>
        mros: (<type 'bool'>, <type 'int'>, <type 'object'>)
        props: ['bit_length', 'conjugate', 'denominator', 'imag', 'numerator', 'real']
    __class__
        type: <type 'type'>: <type 'type'>
    __delattr__
        type: <type 'wrapper_descriptor'>: <slot wrapper '__delattr__' of 'object' objects>
    __doc__
        type: <type 'NoneType'>
        mros: (<type 'NoneType'>, <type 'object'>)
        props: []
    __eq__
        type: <type 'function'>
        source: def __eq__(self, other):
            if other.__class__ is not self.__class__:
                return NotImplemented
    __format__
        type: <type 'method_descriptor'>: <method '__format__' of 'object' objects>
    __ge__
        type: <type 'function'>
        source:     def __ge__(self, other):
                """
                Automatically created by attrs.
                """
                if other.__class__ is self.__class__:
                    return attrs_to_tuple(self) >= attrs_to_tuple(other)
        
                return NotImplemented
    __getattribute__
        type: <type 'wrapper_descriptor'>: <slot wrapper '__getattribute__' of 'object' objects>
    __getstate__
        type: <type 'function'>
        source:         def slots_getstate(self):
                    """
                    Automatically created by attrs.
                    """
                    return tuple(getattr(self, name) for name in state_attr_names)
    __gt__
        type: <type 'function'>
        source:     def __gt__(self, other):
                """
                Automatically created by attrs.
                """
                if other.__class__ is self.__class__:
                    return attrs_to_tuple(self) > attrs_to_tuple(other)
        
                return NotImplemented
    __hash__
        type: <type 'NoneType'>
        mros: (<type 'NoneType'>, <type 'object'>)
        props: []
    __init__
        type: <type 'function'>
        source: def __init__(self, name, id):
            self.name = __attr_converter_name(name)
            self.id = id
            if _config._run_validators is True:
                __attr_validator_name(self, __attr_name, self.name)
                __attr_validator_id(self, __attr_id, self.id)
    __le__
        type: <type 'function'>
        source:     def __le__(self, other):
                """
                Automatically created by attrs.
                """
                if other.__class__ is self.__class__:
                    return attrs_to_tuple(self) <= attrs_to_tuple(other)
        
                return NotImplemented
    __lt__
        type: <type 'function'>
        source:     def __lt__(self, other):
                """
                Automatically created by attrs.
                """
                if other.__class__ is self.__class__:
                    return attrs_to_tuple(self) < attrs_to_tuple(other)
        
                return NotImplemented
    __module__
        type: <type 'str'>
        mros: (<type 'str'>, <type 'basestring'>, <type 'object'>)
        props: ['_formatter_field_name_split', '_formatter_parser', 'capitalize', 'center', 'count', 'decode', 'encode', 'endswith', 'expandtabs', 'find', 'format', 'index', 'isalnum', 'isalpha', 'isdigit', 'islower', 'isspace', 'istitle', 'isupper', 'join', 'ljust', 'lower', 'lstrip', 'partition', 'replace', 'rfind', 'rindex', 'rjust', 'rpartition', 'rsplit', 'rstrip', 'split', 'splitlines', 'startswith', 'strip', 'swapcase', 'title', 'translate', 'upper', 'zfill']
    __ne__
        type: <type 'function'>
        source:     def __ne__(self, other):
                """
                Check equality and either forward a NotImplemented or
                return the result negated.
                """
                result = self.__eq__(other)
                if result is NotImplemented:
                    return NotImplemented
        
                return not result
    __new__
        type: <type 'builtin_function_or_method'>: <built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x55f761d79a20>
    __reduce__
        type: <type 'method_descriptor'>: <method '__reduce__' of 'object' objects>
    __reduce_ex__
        type: <type 'method_descriptor'>: <method '__reduce_ex__' of 'object' objects>
    __repr__
        type: <type 'function'>
        source:     def __repr__(self):
                """
                Automatically created by attrs.
                """
                try:
                    working_set = _already_repring.working_set
                except AttributeError:
                    working_set = set()
                    _already_repring.working_set = working_set
        
                if id(self) in working_set:
                    return "..."
                real_cls = self.__class__
                if ns is None:
                    qualname = getattr(real_cls, "__qualname__", None)
                    if qualname is not None:
                        class_name = qualname.rsplit(">.", 1)[-1]
                    else:
                        class_name = real_cls.__name__
                else:
                    class_name = ns + "." + real_cls.__name__
        
                # Since 'self' remains on the stack (i.e.: strongly referenced) for the
                # duration of this call, it's safe to depend on id(...) stability, and
                # not need to track the instance and therefore worry about properties
                # like weakref- or hash-ability.
                working_set.add(id(self))
                try:
                    result = [class_name, "("]
                    first = True
                    for name, attr_repr in attr_names_with_reprs:
                        if first:
                            first = False
                        else:
                            result.append(", ")
                        result.extend(
                            (name, "=", attr_repr(getattr(self, name, NOTHING)))
                        )
                    return "".join(result) + ")"
                finally:
                    working_set.remove(id(self))
    __setattr__
        type: <type 'wrapper_descriptor'>: <slot wrapper '__setattr__' of 'object' objects>
    __setstate__
        type: <type 'function'>
        source:         def slots_setstate(self, state):
                    """
                    Automatically created by attrs.
                    """
                    __bound_setattr = _obj_setattr.__get__(self, Attribute)
                    for name, value in zip(state_attr_names, state):
                        __bound_setattr(name, value)
        
                    # The hash code cache is not included when the object is
                    # serialized, but it still needs to be initialized to None to
                    # indicate that the first call to __hash__ should be a cache
                    # miss.
                    if hash_caching_enabled:
                        __bound_setattr(_hash_cache_field, None)
    __sizeof__
        type: <type 'method_descriptor'>: <method '__sizeof__' of 'object' objects>
    __slots__
        type: <type 'tuple'>
        mros: (<type 'tuple'>, <type 'object'>)
        props: ['count', 'index']
    __str__
        type: <type 'wrapper_descriptor'>: <slot wrapper '__str__' of 'object' objects>
    __subclasshook__
        type: <type 'builtin_function_or_method'>: <built-in method __subclasshook__ of type object at 0x55f763779300>
    __weakref__
        type: <type 'getset_descriptor'>
        mros: (<type 'getset_descriptor'>, <type 'object'>)
        props: []
    id
        type: <type 'member_descriptor'>
        mros: (<type 'member_descriptor'>, <type 'object'>)
        props: []
    name
        type: <type 'member_descriptor'>
        mros: (<type 'member_descriptor'>, <type 'object'>)
        props: []
```

---

> The easiest way to test performance would be to A/B test a hand crafted version of the class and compare that to the one generated by attrs.

Not easy, but no other choice here. Much appreciated. Hope this is a learning opportunity for others.

Comment: Interesting write up. I wonder if just making a contrived example with a hot loop would help with your argument for switching to a manually created class vs attrs. If the contrived example shows promise, it might give you better justification for doing the more expensive/ realistic testing.

Comment: "Yes and no. I did not write `init`, `@attr` did" — I didn't mean what you coded yourself, I meant that as far as Python knows, the source of both `User` and `User.__init__` is exactly what you reported in your OP. "When we leave `__init__`, those globals **are gone!**" — `compile` creates a module; `globs` will become variables global in that module. There are no cross-module globals in Python, which is why you can't see them outside `__init__`.

Comment: @Amadan That’s nuts. You know, I actually took the weekend to rewrite that massive class with 20 attribs/validators/converters and mine is by far faster in hot code even though those globs are available secretly in init with ‘@attr’. I have to ask people to take my word for it about the globs and just show the speed test comparisons to advocate for removing ‘@attr’. Again, thank you and all.